# How to get autorenewable subscription price from Apple

Tags: ios, subscription, storekit, auto-renewing

I'd like to ask whether there is a way to get price of active auto-renewable subscription by calling some script on Apple's servers? When i verify receipts, there is no price for product id in Apple's server response. And I'd like to get it for logging and stats purposes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I know you can get that on the device as part of the transaction process but I don't think there's a way to do it from your server.

You could maybe cobble it together by sending the price from your app to your server when you send a new receipt.

Comment: that's exact course of action we decided to take... working flawlessly